# How to remove a series of hex values from a string?

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

Using Oracle 11g, I have a string that dumps to the following hex values:

v_string := t
?

```
74:3c:42:52:3e:a:3c:42:52:3e:a
```

I've tried

```
   v_string := REGEXP_REPLACE(v_string,'\x03c\x042\x052\x03e\x0a\x03c\x042\x052\x03e\x0a','');
```

but that doesn't work. How do I remove that string of hex values from v_string leaving v_string = t?

Comment: Have you tried using alternation, i.e., `\x03c|\x042...`?

Comment: So you want `:::::::::` to remain ?

Comment: I don't think I worded my question well. When I get a hex dump of v_string it contains the values listed. I want to remove that series of values from v_string leaving the remaining part of v_string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you appear to be dealing with a string, and you appear to want to remove just exactly that sequence, maybe the problem is that you are thinking of the hex string as being special, whereas it's just a string? perhaps this is what you are looking for?

```
 v_string := REGEXP_REPLACE(v_string,'74:3c:42:52:3e:a:3c:42:52:3e:a','');
```

An example of a full string and it's correct replacement might be  helpful if that's not a useful solution... Not sure I've understood your problem fully.

Comment: You're getting me there and I appreciate your explanation. Notice that 42:52:3e:a appears twice in a row. I want to use regexp_replace to remove the first occurrence of that pattern keeping just one instance of the pattern (42:52:3e:a). When I use the single pattern in regexp_replace, it removes both occurrences. I'd like to keep one instance.

Comment: Ah I see. According to this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm, I think then you want REGEXP_REPLACE(v_string,'42:52:3e:a','',0,1);

Comment: I was unfamiliar with the last two parms available (0,1), I tinkered and used (v_string,'hex_string',1,1) to arrive at a solution...